# App only displayed test ads but not real ads, why?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, banner-ads

I have a ad-id which is working in every other project.
If I try now to display it in my libgdx project then it is not showing.
The code has to be correct beceause test ads are displayed.

Here is my code:

My build.gradle Module: android:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.barodapride.flappy.android/com.barodapride.flappy.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }
    dependencies {

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
    }
    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My AndroidLauncher:

```
package com.barodapride.flappy.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.barodapride.flappy.AdHandler;
import com.barodapride.flappy.FlappyGame;
import com.barodapride.flappy.IActivityRequestHandler;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;


public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdHandler{

    private static final String adUnitId ="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX";
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidLauncher";
    protected AdView adView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView=initializeForView(new FlappyGame(this), config);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

        gameView.setLayoutParams(gameViewParams);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);

        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        layout.addView(adView, topParams);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void showAds(boolean show) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        adView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adView.destroy();
    }
    }
```

And my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.barodapride.flappy.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.barodapride.flappy.android.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why is the banner ad not showing up?

Answer (score 0):

I miss an AddListener that does a callback `onAdLoaded` which tells you, when an add is available.

I can not clearly identify in your code, where you do the link between the `<AdView>` component and your code (missing your xml layout).

Here is a fragment of one of my libgdx games, which displays live ads fine:

In my manifest I use this `metadata` for the `<Application>`

```
<application>
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
```

Then, you have in your xml (at least, I hope so) an `<AdView>` Component.
This component needs a listener.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    super.onAdLoaded();

    // Inform your screen, that the add is loaded
    // Screen shall make the AdView visible -> runOnUiThread!!!
    androidGame.runOnUiThread(50, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This call is from my game engine, just do a callback
            // to your running screen that it shall make the view visible
            if (Engine.get().getActiveScreen() != null)
                Engine.get().getActiveScreen().onBannerAdLoaded();
        }
    });
}
});

adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your test Ad working fine with your App and you're not getting live Ads.

Follow these steps :

1. Wait for some times.
2. After waiting some times/hours if still having problem then you need to cross check Ad unit Id and AppId from AdMob account.
3. If you're able to load test ads but not live ads, it sounds like an issue with your AdMob account.
4. Make sure that you properly set up a payment system and/or verified your PIN? If they are not done, then live ads would not be served from your account.
5. Now you need to post your problem in this [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo) for assistance.